# simple html dom searching for a specific link

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Using Simple html dom parser to get some info links on a web page.

```
a href="http://mysite.com/_/id/5797/name"  John Doe
```

this works just fine

```
$id=5797;
$html = file_get_html("$url");
$echo $html->find("a[href*=$id]",0)->plaintext." <br><hr>";
```

But if I set id to

```
$id=797;
```

It also finds John Doe

So I tried this;

```
$id=5797;
$html = file_get_html("$url");
$echo $html->find("a[href*=id/$id/]",0)->plaintext." <br><hr>";
```

But that returns no matches.  Guessing the something doesn't like the slashes. Is this possible to do with simple html dom or do i need to iterate thru every link and do the checking in php?

thanks

Comment: Try escaping the `/` slashes like this `\/$id\/`

Comment: Thanks much worked like a charm